# Input being chopped off

Tags: c++, string, input, output, iostream

This code looks simple, right?

```
string password;
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, password);
cout << "The user inputted the password: " << password << endl;
```

Well for some reason when i type in *"secret"* as the password the cout results in only *"ecret"*, i.e. it is **chopping off the first character** every time. Why is this?

Comment: That's what `ignore()` does - ignores a character.

Comment: Why do you have `cin.ignore()`?

Comment: @chris Oh thank you, I had a misunderstanding on how that function works :)

Answer (score 1):

`cin.ignore()` ignores the next character of input. That means the `s` in `secret`. I imagine the call is there because of previous troubles of `getline` seeming to skip input (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction)). This only applies when `operator>>` is used and leaves a newline beforehand. I recommend instead doing:

```
getline(std::cin >> std::ws, password);
```

This will remove troubles over leftover whitespace and not cause problems when there is none.

Comment: What is that "std:ws"? I get the rest though, thanks!

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor, It extracts leading whitespace.

Comment: Extracts? Could you explain from the top to the bottom how that line works? :)

Comment: @AxelKennedal-TechTutor, `std::cin >> std::ws` reads the whitespace at the beginning and throws it away. For example, if you have an input buffer of `\n \t Axel Kennedal\n`, the spaces, tab, and newline would be removed and the input buffer would be left with `Axel Kennedal\n`. The returned value of this is `std::cin`, which is what you pass in anyway, but now the buffer is short of the whitespace. Then, `std::getline` goes and reads until the newline like normal, but now it doesn't get any of that whitespace that existed at the beginning of the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this..

```
string password;
cout << "enter password:";
getline(cin, password);
cout << "The user inputted the password: " << password << endl;
```

**Alternatvely**, you can use cin to receive inputs. Now you can use cin.ignore.

```
string password;
cout << "enter password:";
cin >> password;
cin.clear();
cin.ignore(200, '\n');
cout << "The user inputted the password: " << password << endl;
```

It is good to use `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` when you are receiving inputs using `cin >>`.
However, if you are using `getline()`, it seems unnecessary to use `cin.ignore()`.